# What is the syntax to Add a Column to a table using Flink SQL

Tags: apache-flink

given below is the create statement for the table I created using flink.

```
CREATE TABLE event_kafkaTable (
  columnA string,
  columnB string,
  timeofevent string,
  eventTime AS TO_TIMESTAMP(TimestampConverterUtil(timeofevent)),
 WATERMARK FOR eventTime  AS eventTime - INTERVAL '5' SECOND
) WITH (
  'connector' = 'kafka',
  'topic' = 'event_name', 
  'properties.bootstrap.servers'='127.0.0.1:9092',
  'properties.group.id' = 'action_hitGroup',
  'format'= 'json',
  'scan.startup.mode'='earliest-offset',
  'json.fail-on-missing-field'='false', 
  'json.ignore-parse-errors'='true' 
)
```

The table above, listens to Kafka and stores data from the topic in Kafka named event_name. Now, I want to ALTER this table, by adding a new column. Following were the ALTER commands I tried running from my flink job:

```
1. ALTER TABLE event_kafkaTable ADD COLUMN test6 string;
2. ALTER TABLE event_kafkaTable ADD test6 string;
```

Both these commands threw an Flink SQL Parser exception.

The Flink's official website, https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/table/sql/alter.html, has not listed the syntax to add or drop a column from a table. Can you please let me know, what is the syntax to add or drop a column to a table using Flink's Table API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not supported yet in the (default) SQL DDL syntax, but you can use the `AddColumns` and `DropColumns` Table API methods to perform those operations.

[This documentation page](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/tableApi.html#column-operations) has examples on how to use them for each supported language.